# Help identifying children’s book about a chaotic family Halloween and/or thanksgiving

Tags: identification-request

I have a vivid recollection of reading a book about Halloween and/or thanksgiving. My primary recollection is that the book was similar in style to Beverly Cleary, but I don’t believe she was the author. The book opens with a character bemoaning Christmas decorations in sale before Halloween.